# What are w-bit words?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, cpu-architecture

1. What are w-bit words in computer architecture ?
2. For two 7 bit words

> ```
> 1011001 = A 
> 1101011 = B , how does multiplication returns
> ```
>
> 10010100110011     ?

Isn't there simple binary multiplication involved in these ?
Please provide an example.

Comment: actually, that's 'Y' and 'k' not 'A' and 'B'

Comment: Thanks, I think you read the same lecture =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both adding and multiplying are done just the same as in decimal (base 10). You just need to remember this truth table:

```
Multiplying
-----------
0 x 0 = 0
0 x 1 = 0
1 x 0 = 0
1 x 1 = 1

Adding
-----------
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 1 = 0 (w/ carry)
```

First adding. To add, you add just like you would in normal arithmetic, except follow the truth table above:

```
  00000101 = 5
+ 00000011 = 3
--------------
  00001000 = 8
```

How this works is that you start from the right and work left. `1 + 1 = 0`, but you carry a `1` over to the next column. So the next column is `0 + 1`, which would be `1`, but since you carried another `1` from the previous column, its really `1 + 1`, which is `0`. You carry a `1` over the next column, which is `1 + 0`, but really `1 + 1` because of the carry. So `0` again and finally move the `1` to the next column, which is `0 + 0`, but because of our carry, becomes `1 + 0`, which is `1`. So our answer is `1000`, which is `8` in decimal. `5 + 3 = 8`, so we know we are right.

Next, multiplying:

```
  00000101 = 5
x 00000011 = 3
----------
       101 = 5
+     1010 = 10
----------
      1111 = 15
```

How this works is you multiply the top number `00000101` by the right most digit in the second row. So `00000011` is our second row and `1` is the right most digit, so `00000101` times `1` = `101`. Next you put a `0` placeholder in the right most column below it, just like in normal multiplication. Then you multiply our top original number `00000101` by the next digit going left in our original problem `00000011`. Again it produce `101`. Next you simply add `101 + 1010 = 1111` ...That is the answer

Answer (score 3):

w-bit is just the typical nomenclature for n-bit because w is usually short for word size

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's simple binary multiplication:

```
>>> 0b1011001
89
>>> chr(_)
'Y'
>>> 0b1101011
107
>>> chr(_)
'k'
>>> ord('Y') * ord('k')
9523
>>> bin(_)
'0b10010100110011'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply, you simply do the multiplication the same as with decimal numbers, except that you have to add the carries in binary:

```
         1011001
        x1101011
         -------
         1011001
        1011001.
       0000000..
      1011001...
     0000000....
    1011001.....
   1011001......
  --------------
  10010100110011
```

Answer (score 1):

w-bit words aren't anything by themselves.  Assuming that the value of `w` has been previously defined in the context in which "w-bit word" is used, then it simply means a word that is composed of `w` bits.  For instance:

```
A version of RC6 is more accurately specified as RC6-w/r/b where the word size
is "w" bits,  encryption consists of a nonnegative number of rounds "r," and
"b" denotes the length of the encryption key in bytes. Since the AES
submission is targetted at w=32, and r=20, we shall use RC6 as shorthand to
refers to such versions.
```

So in the context of that document, a "w-bit word" is just a 32-bit value.

As for your multiplication, I'm not sure what you are asking.  Google confirms the result as correct:

[1011001](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=89%20%2a%20107#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=0b1011001%20in%20decimal&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c7005364474157f0&biw=1536&bih=1084) * [1101011](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=89%20%2a%20107#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=0b1101011%20in%20decimal&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c7005364474157f0&biw=1536&bih=1084) = [10010100110011](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=89%20%2a%20107#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=89%20%2a%20107%20in%20binary&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c7005364474157f0&biw=1536&bih=1084)